# Show push notifications only when app is in background

Tags: android

I'm using pushy.me push notification service in my android app. It works fine, but I only want to show the push notification when this app is NOT running in foreground.

This are the lines where I build the notification:

```
        // Prepare a notification with vibration, sound and lights
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 1000)
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyApp.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

        // Automatically configure a Notification Channel for devices running Android O+
        Pushy.setNotificationChannel(builder, context);

        // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Build the notification and display it

        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

How can I check if the app is running in foreground?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this at the activity level by having a flag that you set to true in `onResume` and set to false in `onPause`. It depends on the particular architecture of your application, but there is no way to know if an App is in the foreground, only if an Activity is.